# Prepending a sequence with zeros gives `FindGeneratingFunction` hard time

Tags: performance-tuning, integer-sequence

Asking for

```
FindGeneratingFunction[{1, 3, 11, 43, 171, 683, 2731, 10923, 43691, 174763}, t]
```

gives the answer (namely `(1 - 2 t)/(1 - 5 t + 4 t^2)`) almost immediately. However if I prepend zeros in the beginning it takes significantly more time:

```
Timing[FindGeneratingFunction[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 11, 43, 171, 683, 2731, 10923, 43691, 174763}, t]]
```

gives `{20.3438, ((1 - 2 t) t^5)/(1 - 5 t + 4 t^2)}`, while adding one more zero results in the answer

```
DifferentialRoot[Function[{\[FormalY],\[FormalX]},{(7-46 \[FormalX]+90 \[FormalX]^2-48 \[FormalX]^3) \[FormalY][\[FormalX]]+(-1+\[FormalX]) \[FormalX] (-1+2 \[FormalX]) (-1+4 \[FormalX]) (\[FormalY]^\[Prime])[\[FormalX]]==0,\[FormalY][0]==0}]][t]/t
```

I need to add **two** more terms of the sequence to the right to get `((1 - 2 t) t^6)/(1 - 5 t + 4 t^2)`.

Can I improve performance by manipulating options to `FindGeneratingFunction`? There is an option `Method` but I could not find anything in the documentation about it.

Moreover to

```
FindGeneratingFunction[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 6, 6, 22, 22, 86, 86, 342, 342, 1366, 1366, 5462, 5462}, t]
```

(multiplying by two and repeating each term twice) gives `(2^(1 + t) t^5 (1 - 2 t^2))/(1 - t - 4 t^2 + 4 t^3)`, and this I don't understand at all - what is `2^(1 + t)` doing there??

Comment: (1) Please do not use the `bugs` tag until a behavior is *confirmed* as a bug. (2) The zeros make this a different sequence; why don't you remove them if you want the first result?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Will know, thanks. As for the zeros - well sometimes one wants to blindly feed several sequences into a program without knowing whether they start with several zeros or not...

Comment: Would it be a solution to programmatically strip zeros, or possibly repeated elements of any kind, appearing at the start of your list?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, that could work; it would correspond to needing to multiply the result of the stripped version with an appropriate power, and then adding back an appropriate geometric series.

Comment: @J.M. Since `FindSequenceFunction[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 11, 43, 171, 683, 2731, 10923, 43691, 
  174763}]` is fast is there an easy way to use that output to compute a generating function?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, feeding the output of that into `GeneratingFunction[]` *might* work.